# Is a hdd's uuid constant?

Tags: fstab, uuid, motherboard

I know you can change the uuid if you choose, but if left alone does it remain the same.  Specifically I'm upgrading my motherboard but am unsure if I'll need to alter my fstab with new uuids or if all that information will remain the same.

Comment: I don't find an answer to my specifics in that thread.

Comment: The first and only answer tells you when the UUID will change. Changing the mother board will not change the UUID unless you manually change it or reformat the partition or hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it *should* not change. The reasoning for this is because the UUID is stored **in the filesystem metadata**.

However, when you change your motherboard, there may be other settings you need to change. Often a reinstall is required, which will change your UUID.

The only other reason why the UUID would change is if the driver software for the motherboard changes the UUID, but if it does that, you should be questioning why it changes the UUID.

Comment: The file system stores the UUID, not the hard drive. Your UUID will change if you manually change it (command depends on file system) or if you reformat a partition. Otherwise it will not change, or at least I can not recall another scenario where it would change. Generally you do not need to reinstall Linux after changing hardware (mother board), but I think you may need to reinstall or re-license other OS.

Comment: See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fb0d42af-e6bf-490d-860c-3641c22931dc/hard-disk-uuid?forum=winservergen for Microsoft and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID for Ubuntu (other distros similar as it is a property of the file system).